# Overflow margin in medium screen (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

When I use "row" and "container" classes in medium screen I have overflow scroll in my browser. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Dont know cant see your code.

Comment: Does [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) report any errors in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Its because the .row class has margins defined so it cause the scroll.

trying doing this

```
@media (max-height:767px)
{
 .row{
  margin-left:0px!important;
  margin-right:0px!important;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nifal but the container is still too wide.. :(

Comment: I just checked out your site again. Seems to be php scripts thats printed at the bottom of the page. fix that and it should work fine with the styles in my post

Answer (score 1):

Make sure while using bootstrap container is a parent div and row will be child of container, because by default container has padding left and right 15px and row has margin -15px left and right side, and if you will add any custom width inside your container or for container itself, that's the reason you are facing this issue.